# Android Menu only works once per app run

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've hit a weird problem with my Android app.  My main activity has a menu attached to the menu button.  Problem is, the menu button works exactly once.  Once pressed, the app has to be restarted before the menu button will work again.

The (sanitised) code is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class));

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    this.finish();
}
```

and the preferences activity looks like

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I should resolve this?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onCreateOptionsMenu` is only called once, right before you open the OptionsMenu the first time.
Instead use `onPrepareOptionsMenu` to call your `startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class));`
`onPrepareOptionsMenu`is called everytime you click on the Menu-Button.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class));
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: can you expand on this?  Not sure where you mean onPrepareOptionsMenu needs to be.

Comment: You have to override onPrepareOptionsMenu in your Activity Class, like you did with onCreateOptionsMenu. I've updated my answer to show you the code.

Comment: that seems to be working for the main activity but not for the child activity.  When I'm in the child activity and press the menu button, then the back button, I go to the main activity, not the child activity I was in ???

Comment: Don't understand what the problem is. Pressing back in the second activity is supposed to bring you to the main activity.

Comment: Ahh, my child activity had this.finish() in onPause().  Commented that out and it seems to be working.  My thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are starting an Activity instead of showing a menu.
The normal way would be to inflate a menu inside the onCreate Optionsmenu and have a settings item in this menu, that if pressed shows the Preference Activity.

Thommy is right. If you want to start the preference Activity right away (keep in mind that this is unusual behavior for an Android App) you can do this in the onPrepareOptionsMenu. 
In the normal flow the menu is created once in the onCreateOptionsMenu callback and after that it is reused.

Comment: My app has several activities.  The initial activity has a menu (implemented in /res/xml/preferences.xml) as does one of the child activities (implemented similarly).  I want that when the menu button is pressed, the propriate menu is displayed and when the back button is pressed, the calling activity is displayed again.  The user should be able to access the menu as many times as is required.

Comment: thanks for the info.  I'll need to go do some reading on this.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on the menu button you are moving to the PreferencesActivity and whenever you click back over there... the first activity is closed because of the onBackPressed method.

Can you tell me what exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: Do you want the same Menuoptions in all the activities ? Can you please try by removing this.finish() in all the methods and changing the name of the onCreateOptionsMenu method to onPrepareOptionsMenu.

Comment: nope.  The main activity has a menu option to enable or disable the apps 'demo' mode.  Only one child activity has a menu and that is to affect the way that activity works.

Comment: The menu OnCreateOptionsMenu is Activity specific and can not be activated/inherited to the next activities. If you want the menu to be activated in the other activity, then you should again create the options menu separately to that particular activity.